# Is web3.js an Ethereum blockchain client?

Tags: web3js, clients, uport

Reason is that I wanted to know what Ethereum blockchain client uPort uses and someone said it's `web3.js`.

I haven't understood this concept enough since I was expecting something like `eth`, `geth` or `pyethapp`. This may be a noob question but I just wanted to ask to clarify some things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `web3.js` or any other [implementation](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/#other-implementations) is just a "portal" to the actual Ethereum [clients](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/choosing-a-client.html) which accept JSON-RPC calls.

Essentially, instead of you doing custom HTTP calls in JavaScript, the web3 community developed a nice, off-the-shelf package for you to install and use right away. That means that you should either run your own node or connect to a service like [Infura](https://infura.io).

Answer (score 1):

Web3.js is a JavaScript framework for interfacing with a node synchronised to the Ethereum blockchain.

In the same way that jQuery is a framework for achieving more complex requirements without having to write raw JavaScript.

When making requests to an Ethereum node (like those provided by [Infura](https://infura.io)) you have to format your requests in a specific manner - that outlined in the [JSON-RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) specification and implemented by Ethereum node **clients** like [Geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/geth) and [Parity](https://www.parity.io/ethereum/).

Similarly when returning a response web3.js handles lots of the legwork involved in converting the response to a human consumable format.

You can interface with an Ethereum node directly for example by making appropriately formatted CURL requests like those outlined in the [Parity documentation](https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-web3-module.html) but using a library like web3.js saves you from reinventing the wheel and means that developers can focus on their core product.

There are other libraries that do similar things. For example [ethers.js](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/).